# Duvida na modelagem do Banco de Dados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, modelagem

Galera, tenho a tabela Produto, Ingrediente e Venda. O produto contem vários ingredientes, ex: Suponha que seja um misto o Produto, ele contem 1 pão e 2 queijos de Ingrediente, essa composição está guardada numa tabela N para N de Produto e Ingrediente. Mas, entretanto, todavia, o cliente ele pode adicionar ingredientes a mais, então eu pensei em criar uma tabela com esses ingredientes utilizados na venda daquele produto. Entretanto, não tenho a minima ideia de como seria essa modelagem. Alguem pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Produto_Ingredientes é a relação que fala quais ingredientes tem no produto e eu estou em duvida no Ingredientes_usados, pq como que eu ligo produto, ingrediente e venda para eu poder listar os ingredientes utilizados de cada produto? Pois o usuário pode adicionar no seu Lanche, bacon, salada, etc que é fora do padrão que está guardado no produto_ingredientes.

Comment: Mas você quer registrar no banco de dados estes ingredientes adicionais de cada pedido feito? Talvez um outro relacionamento específico para estes ingredientes adicionais possa atender.

Comment: Sim, a ideia é listar esses ingredientes adicionais utilizados na venda, mas não tenho ideia de como iniciar :c. O que acontece, esses ingredientes adicionais já são registrados no banco na tabela ingrediente_produto, lá ele pode adicionar bacon, etc. Só que no caso para listar esses ingredientes "novos" utilizados, deveria ter outra tabela e essa tabela tá confusa pra mim, pq não sei se posso ligar Venda, Produto, Ingrediente, ou se tem uma forma melhor.

Comment: Seria uma outra tabela, similar à ingrediente-produto, específica para os itens opcionais efetivamente adicionados e também ligada a venda. Me parece que não deve estar relacionada a produto.

Comment: Mas como iria saber que aquele ingrediente utilizado foi utilizado em um determinado produto? Tipo, comprei X-Tudo e X-Salada e adicionei um ovo no X-Salada, como vou saber que esse ovo é do X-Salada?

Comment: O ovo não está relacionado a todos os x-salada, está relacionado apenas aquele x-salada específico cujo cliente solicitou. Poderia ser adicionado ao x-salada ou a qualquer outro produto. Você tem que definir precisamente os requisitos de seu modelo e o que ele precisa atender.

Comment: É isso que eu quero que você citou. Nesse caso eu ligaria ingredientes - ingredientes_usados - vendas?

Comment: Tabela `venda_produtos` que relaciona venda e produtos. Tabela `venda_produto_adicionais` que relaciona o produto daquela venda aos ingredientes adicionais.

Comment: Essa tabela, venda_produto_adicionais teria venda, produto e o ingrediente?

Comment: Você já resolveu seu problema. O que lhe falta é criar um view de 'produtos' x 'igredientes' com 'produto_igredientes' como pivot mais as procedures de inserção, exclusão, atualização.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não entendi por que teria que criar uma view e procedures. Só com tabelas e operações de negócio não atende os requisitos do AP? Não consigo ver utilidade na view porque é um conceito com o qual tive pouco contato, de repente você tem outra visão (com o perdão do trocadilho).

Comment: @GabrielSereno Só umas perfumarias, na sua modelagem está faltando um campo **quantidade** na tabela produto (ex: misto = 2 queijos) e nas outras tabelas trocar o tipo dos campos **valor** de _float_ para _decimal_.

Comment: @GabrielSereno, é que você fez certinho. A modelagem atende seu problema, como o Piovezan falou falta apenas detalhes. Sugeri um view porque o view possibilita uma visão integrada de seus dados, mas seu uso não é mandatório. Apenas facilita na busca de dados para exibição.No front end  ao invés de usar `joins` em cada busca você utilizaria um simples `select`. Mas isso é só detalhe.

Comment: Obrigado gente :D

Comment: @Piovezan. Desculpe-me, só agora que identifiquei que o comentário dirigido foi feito por você. Eu o respondi direcionado ao Gabriel. Piovezan tabela e operações de negócios sim atendem os requisitos. O view é uma facilidade que visa concentrar dados de múltiplas tabelas em uma única tabela virtual. Qual a vantagem? A vantagem é simplificação do raciocínio, ao invés de olhar para um conjunto de tabelas, analisar suas estruturas de relacionamentos para então deduzir uma estrutura de dados o uso do view    abrevia essas inferências expondo diretamente a estrutura de dados pretendida.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Entendi, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 1):

Cara vc pode colocar uma coluna "tipo"(ou qualquer nome que queira) na tabela produto_ingredientes e colocar valores como "padrão" ou "adicionado", ou então 0 e 1 mesmo, pra dizer se o ingrediente faz parte do produto original ou foi adicionado.

Depois com um inner join vc consegue listar os ingredientes adicionados em cada lanche.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, o método mais prático que aprendi (e que entrou na minha cabeça) foi: fazer a tabela à mão (ou no excel) do resultado final dos dados que vc espera obter e/ou guardar (ex: comanda, nota fiscal **ficha** **de** **pedidos**). E, a partir daí, vai normalizando, pelo menos, até a terceira forma normal.

Ao final, você estará com todas as relações prontas sem precisar quebrar a cabeça com regra de negócio.

Resumindo: Desenhe o seu formulário inicial > Normalize os campos

Sobre normalização, tem bastante material na internet para todos os gostos, de vídeo aulas no youtube à trabalhos acadêmicos.